# Program will not run - letter frequency of book calculator

Tags: c

I am trying to find the word frequency and I cannot figure out why the program keeps crashing.. I have tried so many ways, yet I am still getting the same crash. Am I doing something wrong? *The input is a book file and a new file I want to create.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    FILE *fp,*fp2;
    int ch, total, counter, totalcounter, i;
    int letters[25], letterfrequency[25];
    for(i=0; i<25; i++)
    {
        letters[i] = 0;
        letterfrequency[i] = 0;
    }
    printf("Opening: %s", argv[1]);
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
        {
            perror("fopen");
            exit(1);
        }
    while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
                {
                    counter = toupper(ch);
                    ch = counter - 65;
                    letters[ch]++;
                    totalcounter++;
                }
        }

    fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp2, "%c: Times used: %s\tFrequency Used: %s", i+65, letters[i], letters[i]/totalcounter);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has a ton of warnings. Be sure to compile with `-Wall`. Fix the warnings. Then repost the code if it still isn't working.

Comment: How are you trying to run this? What is the expected output?

Comment: you can add printing of values of `ch`, it could help to identify the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems. First is that it has warnings. These warnings are pointing at problems. Unfortunately most C compilers won't show you warnings by default. You have to turn them on with `-Wall`. But `-Wall` doesn't mean "all warnings", oh no. If you ask why, the short answer is that C is an accumulation of decades of questionable design choices, get used to it. :-/ I run with even more warnings and checks: `-Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g`.

There's a bunch of unused and uninitialized variables, your printf specification is wrong, and you're missing an `include` for `toupper`. I'll leave you to fix all that.

---

Then the next problem is you've initialize `letters` to be 25 long, but the alphabet has 26 characters. Fortunately you're also only iterating over them 25 times, but that means you'll lose 'Z'. This is an easy mistake to make. A 26 item long array goes from 0 to 25, but its length is 26.

Rather than repeat the length of the array all over the place, and probably miss one, it's better to define it in one place.

```
#define NUM_LETTERS 26
```

Then there's a faster and simpler way to initialize an array.

```
int letters[NUM_LETTERS] = {0};
```

There's no need to specify every element, C will fill in the rest with the last element.

---

Since it's totally safe to call `toupper` on something that's not a character, it just returns the character unchanged, you can simplify your `while` loop.

```
while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    ch = toupper(ch);
    if( 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ) {
        ch -= 65;
        letters[ch]++;
        totalcounter++;
    }
}
```

Note the style I used, `'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z'`. This makes it easier to see that it's a check for `ch` inside the range from `A` to `Z`.

---

The next problem is this: `letters[i]/totalcounter`.

In C, if you divide two integers you get an integer. That means `20/100` is `0`. If you want a decimal, you have to cast one of the variables involved to a floating point type: `(double)letters[i]/totalcounter)`.

---

There's the possibility that no letters were read from the file and `totalcounter` is 0. If so `letters[i]/totalcounter` will cause a divide-by-zero error. So you have to check for that case.

```
if( totalcounter != 0 ) {
    for( i=0; i<NUM_LETTERS; i++ ) {
        printf("%c: Times used: %d\tFrequency Used: %f\n",
               i+65, letters[i], (double)letters[i]/totalcounter
        );
    }
}
else {
    printf("No letters found.\n");
}
```

---

You fail to check if the user gave you a filename argument. If they don't, your program will crash. It's important to add a usage check.

```
if( argc < 2 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
```

---

And note that I'm not writing the results to a file, and I have my version only taking one file, the one to read. My version outputs to stdout.

In general, it's better to print program results to stdout than to a file. This allows the program to work well with shell piping which makes it much more flexible.

```
./wordcount somefile                      # output to the screen
./wordcount somefile.txt > somefile.count # output to a file
./wordcount somefile.txt | program        # output to another program
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your arrays to take all letters i.e. `int letters[26];` the other `letterfrequence` you don't seem to use for anything

Your `fprintf` format specifier is wrong

You have

`fprintf(fp2, "%c: Times used: %s\tFrequency Used: %s", 
    i+65, letters[i], letters[i]/totalcounter);`

but `letters` is an int array so correct specifier should be `%d` (int) and not `%s` (string)

You have not initialized `totalcounter` so a 0 division could occur or some other arbitrary division.

`toupper` is in header `ctype.h`, that header is missing.